# ASP.NET MVC: How to disable SSL 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, ssl, https

**Is it possible to disable SSL 2.0 in my MVC project?**

SSL 2.0 contains a number of security flaws (risk of man-in-the-middle attacks etc.; see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#SSL_2.0) for more details). So I want to prevent unsecured HTTPS requests via SSL 2.0 protocol.

I know about `RequireHttps` attribute, but it do not allow to specify required SSL version.

Comment: SSL settings would be set in IIS if a Windows server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC framework knows nothing about SSL types.  All it can help determine is whether or not a page has to be served over a secure connection (Https).  As for what types of secure connections can be made to the server is an IIS configuration setting.

Comment: So answer is - it is impossible. Thank you.